# public static string Name { get; set } как это строка будет выглядеть в java

Tags: java, c#

Здравствуйте у меня есть строка в C#

```
static string Name { get; set }
```

как это строка будет выглядеть в java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2963243/6808809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде как-то так:

```
private static String _name;
private static String getName() { return _name; }
private static String setName(String val) { return _name = val; }
```

Comment: Где то читал, что компилятор C# тоже преобразует в подобную конструкцию.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, ну по сути да. Но в коде свойства гораздо удобнее :)